# New Draggable is reseting scroll after dragging

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm using **Draggable** to insert events and when I start dragging an event I have a funcion to scroll to *fullcalendar div*.

```
    new Draggable(this.marcacaoVisitaAguardarMarcacao.nativeElement, {
      itemSelector: '.class-drag',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {        
        let evento = JSON.parse(eventEl.dataset.event);

        evento = evento.__zone_symbol__value;

        evento.create = false;

        let top = $("#fullcalendarDiv").offset().top;
        let navHeight = $('#navbar').height();

        window.scroll({top: top - navHeight - 24, behavior: 'smooth'});
        $("#fullcalendarDiv").focus();

        return evento;
      }
    });
```

When I strat dragging, the funcion works well but the second I move the mouse, the scroll resets itself and goes to the starting position.

For example:
[image]